# When I post the data ,the data will save repeatedly into database

Tags: magento-1.9, model

How to check weather the value is in database when i insert the data[image: Value repeatedly save to database]

```
$amount_model = Mage::getModel('donations/amount');
if(isset($post_data['amount']) && $post_data['amount'] != '')
{
    $amountdata = $post_data['amount'];
    foreach(array_unique($amountdata) as $amount) {
        $amount['donation_id'] = $dataid;
        $amount_model->setData($amount);
        $amount_model->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code which you try for the save?

Comment: Your code is not clear, if you want to save the values just once example `5` one time in your database, you have to get all values before then you check if the new value is not available in database, you insert it.

Comment: How to get value all values first